# Syntax highlighting for numbers

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I often post benchmarks and then the results look  partly colored:

[image: colored]

Sometimes someone edits my post to change the syntax highlighting from default to text, and then it looks like this:

[image: uncolored]

I prefer the numbers to stand out being highlighted. One benefit in this case is that it shows the equivalent structure of the two table titles and how they relate.

But I agree it's text, not some programming language, so the editor is right. And I wish those thousands-commas would be colored as well. And sometimes I use words that happen to be keywords or standard identifiers of the language and get highlighted when I don't want that.

Is there a proper way to declare it as `lang-text-with-numbers` or so, to make everyone happy?

Comment: An option for this is to explicitly use `lang-json`, which has a very limited highlighting set and indeed appears to show what you're looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgiGA.png. Potentially it having `lang-json` applied will discourage people applying the text formatting

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine I guess that might be a better half-measure solution, but still would be incorrect and the thousands-commas are still white.

Comment: For `text` like this, the colouring of the numbers really shouldn't matter, in my opinion. I sometimes actually find the numbers being coloured distracting.

Comment: @Larnu Well, I don't want to force everyone to use it :-). But like I said, I like it better, so for my own posts I'd like to do it. In my [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71520401/12671057) you can see I actually have *two* tables, and one benefit of colors is that it immediately [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vMGk.png) the equivalent structure of the two table titles and how they relate.

Comment: None of the 47 (currently) supported language families (excluding all aliases) provide this described behaviour. Specifically none will highlight the comma thousands separator as part of the number. (Likely in part due to the fact that that would require specifying a locale or identifying decimal/thousands delimiters)

Comment: @HenryEcker Wow, did you try them all? Thanks :-) I didn't, because I didn't want to declare an incorrect language anyway, and I didn't see one that sounded correct. I don't know about all the world's locales, but at least the main stackoverflow site is English, and I imagine a good simple solution for most cases would something like streaks of digits, potentially including commas, periods and underscores and a minus sign. Potential regex: `-?\b[0-9](?:[0-9,._]*[0-9])?\b` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/oDFHcF/1) and [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lidZx.png)).

Comment: I'm familiar with the markdown for most of the highlighters Stack Overflow supports, but in this case I did write a quick program to generate the markdown and scrolled through to confirm. You are correct you could just look for all numbers, commas, and decimals _and_ it would be very easy to create a language definition for highlight.js which would provide this behaviour. Assuming, of course, a regex could be nailed down to match only what you wanted it to. (Though that is certainly easier said than done especially if one wanted to exclude specific numbers like dates, IP Addresses, _etc._)

Comment: Regardless of whether a custom regex could be worked out or not, Stack Exchange uses a [subset](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/1099857) of the [supported languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) of highlight.js (with a few custom aliases). highlight.js generally only supports syntax highlighting for programming languages. Given that this type of highlighting is not a programming language I’d be surprised if it ended up in the supported languages list and adopted by Stack Exchange.

Comment: People won't know that you want that unless you communicate it to them. They will reasonably assume that it's a mistake unless you tell them that's actually what you wanted. Have you tried leaving a note in the Markdown just above the start of the code block? It could be something like `<!-- I want the syntax highlighting the way that it is (i.e. highlighting the numbers). Please don't change it.-->`.

Comment: @Makyen No I haven't, and I'm not sure I'd feel comfortable with that. I'm not complaining about their editing. Like I said, I agree the default language (some programming language) is incorrect, and also has issues of styling too little (commas) or too much (keywords and standard identifiers).

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge: if you want to post a table, why don't you post a table?

```markdown
* 10 iterables of 10,000 to 90,000 elements, first has 50,000:

    |     min |     avg |     max | user              |
    | ------: | ------: | ------: | :---------------- |
    | 49.9 ms | 50.1 ms | 50.4 ms | CrazyChucky       |
    | 74.3 ms | 74.6 ms | 75.1 ms | Mad_Physicist     |
    |  2.5 ms |  2.6 ms |  2.6 ms | Kelly_Bundy_chain |
    |  2.3 ms |  2.3 ms |  2.3 ms | limit_cheat       |
```

- 10 iterables of 10,000 to 90,000 elements, first has 50,000:

  | min | avg | max | user |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 49.9 ms | 50.1 ms | 50.4 ms | CrazyChucky |
  | 74.3 ms | 74.6 ms | 75.1 ms | Mad_Physicist |
  | 2.5 ms | 2.6 ms | 2.6 ms | Kelly_Bundy_chain |
  | 2.3 ms | 2.3 ms | 2.3 ms | limit_cheat |

Comment: Doesn't highlight the numbers, either, but now that they're *really* just text, I could highlight them myself by making them bold (at least the ones in the table "title").